# Stipulated in columns in sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

table1:

```
kalaname | to | tbox | tkh | price | pricek
```

---

sql query is:

```
select kalaname , if(to=0,'0',str(to) + '*' + str(tbox)) as computeto , 
       tkh , price , pricek 
from table1    ------- Error
```

How do you put condition on the column?

Comment: What types are the to and tbox columns? And what is the expected result? A string or a multiplication or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `CASE` statement. Try something like this:

```
select 
  kalaname , 
  CASE WHEN (to = 0) THEN '0', ELSE str(to) + '*' + str(tbox) END as computeto, 
  tkh , price , pricek 
from table1
```

Depending on what type the `to`and `tbox`columns are, the conversion might and string concatenation might not get you the expected result. You could try using `CAST(to AS VARCHAR(20)) + '*' + CAST(tbox AS VARCHAR(20))`instead.

Answer (score 3):

you have to use a CASE... WHEN ... ELSE ... END clause.

```
case when to = 0 
          then '0'
          else str(to) + '*' + str(tbox)
end as computeto
```

By the way, you may be surprised by the result of str in a concatenation.
You may need to LTRIM / RTRIM the result of str.

something like

`LTRIM(RTRIM(STR(to))) + '*' + LTRIM(RTRIM(STR(to)))`

or

```
REPLACE(STR(to), ' ', '')
```